# How can i display the data from my mongoose/mongodb database into a pug template using loop?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I have tried using

```js
router.get('/entries', (req, res) => {
    database.find({}, function (err, database) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.render('entries', {database: database});
            console.log(database)
    }

        
    });
    
})
```

and

```js
    body
        -var database = database;
        ul
            each database, i in database
                li= database.name
```

but this gives an error. Most of the time it is **"cannot read property 'length' of undefined"**

here is my schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


var DataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  
  France: {
    name: 'string',
    productType: 'string',
    company: 'string',
    
  },
  Russia: {
    name: 'string',
    productType: 'string',
    company: 'string',
   
  },

})


module.exports = mongoose.model('database', DataSchema);
```

Is there any module that i need to install to make this work?

Comment: what is your `console.log(database)` outputting?

Comment: It ran fine and gave all the documents from the database.

Comment: [{
    France: {
      name: 'something',
      productType: 'cookware',
      company: 'xcompany'
    },
    Russia: { name: 'hellobro' },
    _id: 5ec684cffcd08843202a3084,
    __v: 0
  },
  { _id: 5ec6854bfcd08843202a3085, __v: 0 },
  {
    France: { name: 'France Toy', productType: 'ToY', company: 'France Co.' },
    _id: 5ec68840c1583c326800577e,
    __v: 0
  },]